# Python homework programming

Tags: python, command, document

I have python homework, most part of homework have done, but i have issues with remaining. So:

According to the task we have list of all documents:

1.

```
documents = [
{‘type’: ‘passport’, ‘number’: ‘2207 876234’, ‘name’: ‘Vasily Gupkin’},
{‘type’: ‘invoice’, ‘number’: ‘11-2’, ‘name’: ‘Gennady Pokemono’},
{‘type’: ‘insurance’, ‘number’: ‘10006’, ‘name’: ‘Aristarkh Pavlov’}
]
```

**The list of shelves where documents are stored (if the document is in documents, then it must also be in directories):**

```
directories = {
‘1’: [‘2207 876234’, ‘11-2’],
‘2’: [‘10006’],
‘3’: []
}
```

**The task is to a user can add a new document to the data with the “ad” command.**

Example:

1. Enter the command:
   ad

Enter document number:
42
Enter document type:
multipassport
Enter document owner:
R2D2
Enter Storage Shelf:
3
Result:

The document has been added. Current list of documents:
№: 2207 876234, type: passport, owner: Vasily Gupkin, storage shelf: 1
№: 11-2, type: invoice, owner: Gennady Pokemonov, storage shelf: 1
№: 10006, type: insurance, owner: Aristarkh Pavlov, storage shelf: 2
no: 42, type: multipassport, owner: R2D2, storage shelf: 3

2.

Enter the command:
ad

Enter document number:
42
Enter document type:
multipassport
Enter document owner:
R2D2
Enter Storage Shelf:
4
Result:

Such a shelf does not exist. Add a shelf with the as command.
Current list of documents:
№: 2207 876234, type: passport, owner: Vasily Gupkin, storage shelf: 1
№: 11-2, type: invoice, owner: Gennady Pokemonov, storage shelf: 1
№: 10006, type: insurance, owner: Aristarkh Pavlov, storage shelf: 2

**Now i have this code:**

```
def get_name():
     number = input('Enter document number ')
     for data in documents:
         if data.get("number") == number:
             return data.get('name')
     return 'Document not found in database'


def get_shelf_in():
     number = input('Enter document number ')
     return get_shelf(number)

def get_shelf(number):
     for key in directories:
         if number in directories.get(key):
             return key
     return 'Document not found in database'

def get_list():
     output=''
     for doc in documents:
         output = output + f"#{doc['number']}, type: {doc['type']}, owner: {doc['name']}, storage shelf: {get_shelf(doc['number'] )}" + '\n'
     return output



def add_doc():
     shelf = input('Enter the number of the shelf where to put the document. ')
     if shelf not in directories:
         return 'No such shelf'
     doc = {}
     for info in ('type', 'number', 'name'):
         doc[info] = input(f'{info}: ')
     directories[shelf] = directories.get(shelf).append(doc['number'])
     return 'Document added'


def add_pol():
     number= input("Enter shelf number: ")
     if number in directories.keys():
         print(f"Such a shelf already exists. Current list of shelves: {shelf_list()}")
     else:
         directories[number] = []
         print(f"Shelf added. Current shelf list: {shelf_list()}")




def delete_shelf():
     number= input("Enter shelf number: ")
     if number not in directories:
         print(f"No such shelf exists. Current shelf list: {shelf_list()}.")
     elif len(directories[number]) == 0 :
         del directories[number]
         print(f"Shelf removed. Current shelf list: {shelf_list()}.")
     else:
         print(f"There are documents on the shelf, please remove them before removing the shelf. Current shelf list: {shelf_list()}.")


def shelf_list():
     return ', '.join(list(directories.keys()))


documents = [
     {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Vasily Gupkin"},
     {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Gennady Pokémonov"},
     {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Document owner Aristarkh Pavlov"}
]

directories = {
     '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
     '2': ['10006'],
     '3': []
}

while True:
     print('Available commands to use: p, s, l, a, ads, ds, ad, q')
     command = input('Enter command name: ')

     if command == 'p':
         print(get_name())

     elif command == 's':
         print(get_shelf_in())

     elif command == 'l':
         print(get_list())

     elif command == 'a':
         print(add_doc())

     elif command == 'ads':
         add_pol()

     elif command == 'ad':
         add_info()

     elif command == 'q':
         break
```

**I can't understand how to put new info to document's list. What commands are responsible for this?

I tried write this:**

```
def add_info():
    number = input('Enter document number: ')
    type = input('Enter document type: ')
    name = input('Enter document owner: ')
    shelf = input('Enter storage shelf: ')
    if shelf not in directories:
       print (f"Such a shelf does not exist. Add a shelf with the **as** command. Current list of documents: {documents()}" + '\n'
    doc = {}
    for info in ('type', 'number', 'name', 'shelf'):
        doc[info] = input(f'{type}:, {number}:, {name}:, {shelf}: ')
    print (f"The document has been added. Current list of documents: {documents()}"
```

but it's not working.

Comment: "not working" is not an adequate description of whatever problem you are having. Be specific: provide a [mcve], state what output/result is expected, and what output/result you are getting instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.